# Proof that every group of order 847 is abelian.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

How would I use Sylow's theorems to prove that any group of order 847 is abelian?  I know that every group of prime order is cyclic, and thus, abelian.  However, $847 = 7*11*11$, thus, is not a prime number.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, both Sylow subgroups are normal. That makes this an easy one.

Comment: Are Sylow subgroups normal in general?

Comment: If they were always normal the Sylow theorems would be a lot less useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $n_p$ denote the number of $p$-Sylow subgroups of $G$. We are interested in $n_7$ and $n_{11}$. We know that

1. $n_7\mid 121$, $n_7\equiv 1\pmod{7}$
2. $n_{11}\mid 7$, $n_{11}\equiv 1\pmod{11}$

It follows that $n_7=n_{11}=1$, can you see why? If $A$ is the $7$-Sylow subgroup and $B$ is the $11$-Sylow subgroup, we have $G\cong A\times B$.

Can you finish?

Comment: Oh, I see.  Every finite abelian group is the product of cyclic groups.  Also, a group is cyclic if it is of prime order.  So we must show that $G\cong A\times B$, where $A$ and $B$ are subgroups of $G$ by using the internal direct product.  In order to use the internal direct product $A \cap B = \{ e \}$, $A$ and $B$ must be abelian with respect to each other, and $AB = G$.  $A$ can be a Sylow 7-subgroup and $B$ can be a Sylow 11-subgroup.  Since each element in $A$ is some power of $7$ and each element of $B$ is some power of $11$ then $A \cap B = {e}$.  How would I show that $AB = G$?

Comment: Also,  how would I show that $A$ and $B$ are abelian with respect to each other?

Comment: @PiccolMan It's a general result that if all Sylow subgroups are normal then the group is the direct product of them. Now $A$ is clearly abelian; what about $B$?

Comment: I know that every group of order $p^{2}$ is abelian, but I don't know why.  $|B| = 11^{2}$, thus, $B$ is abelian. But why is this true?

Comment: @PiccolMan Well, $B\cong G/A$.

Comment: How do you know that A and B are normal?

Comment: @PiccolMan The conjugate of a $p$-Sylow subgroup is a $p$-Sylow subgroup; if there's only one, it's self-conjugate, hence normal.