# Prove that every group of order $45$ is cyclic

Tags: group-theory, cyclic-groups, sylow-theory

Prove that all groups of order $45$ are cyclic.

I was thinking about this proof for a long time and my professor said that it can be proved correctly but I’m not sure about that.

I was trying to figure it out using just:

$\gcd(45,\phi(45))$ but this is equal to $3$ not $1.$

I have read about Sylow’s theorem and I have seen someone was trying to match it with a abelian groups because $45=3^2\times 5$ etc.
But I don’t know how to do it.

Comment: What about $\Bbb Z/3\Bbb Z\times\Bbb Z/3\Bbb Z\times\Bbb Z/5\Bbb Z$. If you want to show that it's **abelian** then maybe duplicate of [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2040977/proof-that-every-group-of-order-847-is-abelian).

Comment: It isn't true, in fact the description of all groups of order $45$ are [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/108405). Check the answer, where it's shown that there are only two such groups.

Comment: I have seen that before and exactly:

Comment: We can clearly see that we can get $Z_3 x Z_3 x Z_5$ and also $Z_9 x Z_5$ for both $gcd$ is equal to 1 but what can I do with $Z_15xZ_3$?

Answer (score 2):

Let's do a description of groups of order 45. By the third Sylow's theorem, the number of subgroups of order $5$ must divide $45$, and must be congruent to $1$ modulo $5$; so there is an unique subgroup of order $5$. On the other hand, the number of subgroups of order $9$ must divide $45$ and be congruent to $1$ modulo $3$; so also there is an unique subgroup of order $9$.

The subgroup of order $5$ must be isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_5$ becuase that's the only group of order 5 up to isomorphism, and the subgroup of order $9$ that could be isomorphic to either $\mathbb{Z}_9$ or to $\mathbb{Z}_3\times\mathbb{Z}_3$ (since p^2 groups are abelian and the torsion coefficients of 9 could be (3,3) and (9)).

Because they are the unique p-subgroups both of them are normal; let $H_5$ be the $5$-Sylow subgroups, and $H_9$ be the $3$-Sylow subgroup. Then $H_5\cap H_9=\{1\}$ since $gcd(5,9)=1$, and $H_5H_9$ is a subgroup (both are normal). Also we know that
$$|H_5H_9| = \frac{|H_5|\,|H_9|}{|{1}|} = 5\times 9 = 45 = |G|,$$
so $G=H_5H_9$. Since both are normal and have coprime orders then $G=H_5H_9\cong H_5\times H_9\cong \mathbb{Z}_5\times H_9$. Since there are two possibilities for the subgroup of order 9 then we have only two groups of order 45:
$$\mathbb{Z}_5\times \mathbb{Z}_9\;\;\;\mathbb{Z}_5\times \mathbb{Z}_3 \times \mathbb{Z}_{3}$$
Both of them abelian but only the first one is cyclic, so the statement is false

Comment: That means I was right and my professor makes mistake?

Comment: If your professor says that they are all cyclic, yes, he is wrong

Comment: I’m pretty sure that he said that “ show me that every group of order 45 is cyclic or you get out”

Comment: If that's true, show him my answer hahaha, maybe he will get out

Comment: I will! Sometimes they get crazy when something went wrong and that’s why I was thinking how to prove it. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: I suspect that “ show me that every group of order 45 is cyclic or you get out” is a convoluted way of saying "Get out!". Perhaps your professor was growing impatient?